# SQL command not working through C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Ok so I am having a mind bender moment here and cannot for the life of me work out why the following code only works intermittently.

When I run the following code I usually get a result from the database, but I recently found an item which returns an error `ORA-01858 a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.` I have tried debugging the code and copy pasting the exact runtime SQL command into Toad for Oracle and it returns results without problems, just not in my app?

Code:

```
            using (var conn = OracleConnect(username, password))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT(ENTITYID) FROM MY.DATABASE WHERE ITEM_ID = '" + itemid + "'";
                using (var oleCmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd, conn)) //ORA-01858 exception here
                {
                    using (var oleRead = oleCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (oleRead.Read())
                        {
                            string entity = oleRead["ENTITYID"].ToString();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity)) _entityid.Add(entity);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any ideas?

**RESOLVED thanks to Hassan**

I tried `using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;` `OracleConnection` with `OracleCommand` and it seems to work, not sure why `OleDb` didn't.

Comment: print sql query (cmd) in debug and check

Comment: @masum7 That was the first thing I did, and I copy pasted it in Toad for Oracle and it works fine, just not in my app?

Comment: Is `MY.DATABASE` a view or a table? What exact datatype is `ITEM_ID` (i.e VARCHAR2(10)). Help for that error indicates it's failing when trying to cast to a date datatype.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid `My.Database` is a view, `ITEM_ID` is `VARCHAR2(9)` and `ENTITYID` is `VARCHAR2(350)` strange it works for other items just not for a small handful. And i have checked the items they look valid.

Comment: It's a problem in your view. Are you comfortable to post the view script? The reason it happens intermittently is sometimes it doesn't have to process the records with issues in your view, depending on the query plan, parameters etc. If you don't want to paste your view, take a careful look at the source and identify all logic that is casting to a date using `TO_DATE` OR more importantly, comparing a column of type date with a column with a different data type (this is called an implicit cast)

Comment: To put it another way, if you select from your view (without a filter) and scroll all the way to the bottom of the dataset you might see the error (again, depending on the query plan). Sometime the query plan will filter out the offending rows before it get to the bug in the view. Sometimes it won't. The solution is not to write buggy views!

Answer (score 3):

```
using (var conn = OracleConnect(username, password))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT(ENTITYID) FROM MY.DATABASE WHERE ITEM_ID =?";
                using (var oleCmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd, conn))
                {
                    oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", itemid);
                    using (var oleRead = oleCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (oleRead.Read())
                        {
                            string entity = oleRead["ENTITYID"].ToString();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity)) _entityid.Add(entity);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Like this should work and use parameters to protect your application from sql injection ! Also if this is serious application please make Database connection on different layer.

Comment: I think for parameters `?` is used instead of `@` sign for the case of [`OleDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Not working.. And yes I am using different layer for db conn, for sake of short sample code I added it above.

Comment: @HassanNisar strange in this example is with '@' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx, but in the documentation is with '?' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could it be something to do with the item id in the database? Maybe it has some unknown character which is being picked up by the code?

Comment: Although I have checked and all the values look the same to me. As previously mentioned, it is very strange that it works in a SQL app but not in my app. Anymore ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @HassanNisar I apologize, `OracleCommand` does seem to return results! Not sure why `OleDb` doesn't! Looks like I will have to rewrite the code using `OracleConnection`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

remove the double single quote in the WHERE condition. May be your ITEM_ID is integer but you passes a string value. Here's the revised code

```
string cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT(ENTITYID) FROM MY.DATABASE WHERE ITEM_ID = " + itemid + "";
```

in database it will generate this script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ENTITYID) FROM MY.DATABASE WHERE ITEM_ID = 1
```

Comment: should not matter, database is smart enough to convert, it is the opposite that can break

Comment: ITEM_ID is alphanumeric

Answer (score -2):

ITEM_ID is alphanumeric (int) and not a varchar. so the value of "itemid" you are passing is rejected because it's not alphanumeric.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Alphanumeric is not (int) it means both numbers and alphabetic chars mixed. Essentially, alphanumeric can mean varchar. The value which I am passing is alphanumeric.